# flutter create ui using stack . Floating Button should be over the widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am tring to create ui as below image. but button hide behind the list. Also faces issue button not click when used `Positioned` widget for button.Please suggest how to create below UI using `Stack` widget with `ListView` & `Floating button`.

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vn4W.jpg)

```
Container(
  color: Colors.grey,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 250.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "images/1.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 220.0,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 250.0,
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 250.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text("Title $index"),
                        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 15,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Added. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html):

> The stack paints its children in order with the first child being at the bottom

So your `Stack` children's order is wrong. Your current order is:

- Header
- Button
- List

But it should be:

- Header
- List
- Button

Otherwise list is overlapping button.